# PHP DOM grabbing a specific subset of information

Tags: php, domdocument

The webpage in question is http://assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&pub=20060030630

Now, let's just say I want to capture the Assignees in the first assignment.  The relevant code there looks like

```
   <div class="t3">Assignee:</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td><td>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tbody valign="top">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div class="p1">
        <a href="/assignments/q?db=pat&amp;asned=LEAR%20CORPORATION">LEAR CORPORATION</a>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
   <td><span class="p1">21557 TELEGRAPH ROAD</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><span class="p1">SOUTHFIELD, MICHIGAN 48034</span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

I could I suppose use xpath and grab everything out of spans with class p1, except that thing is used all throughout the page for basically everything, same for the div class that lear corporation is in.

So is there a way for me to just read "Assignees" and then grab just the information relevant to it?

I figure if I can understand how to do that, then I can extrapolate from that and figure out how to grab any specific data on the page that I want, i.e. grabbing the conveyance data on any particular assignment.

But if say, I were just to grab all the data on the page (reel/frame, conveyance, assignors, assignee, correspondent for every assignment, and the header information about the patent itself), might that be easier to do than trying to grab each individual piece of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear way to do it since we have no designation in the DOM where this information is.. It's very arbitrary.

I would recommend using some math to figure out the pattern of where in the DOM the Assignee resides.

For example, we know that for every class of `p1`, the assignee value is position `16`, and a new Assignment occurs every `23rd` position. Using a loop you could figure it out.

This should get you started at the very least.

```
$Site = file_get_contents('http://assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&pub=20060030630');

$Dom = new DomDocument();
$Dom->loadHTML($Site);
$Finder = new DomXPath($Dom);
$Nodes = $Finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' p1 ')]");

$position = 0;
foreach($Nodes as $node) {
    if(($position % 16) == 0 && $position > 0) {
        var_dump($node->nodeValue);
        break;
    }
    $position++;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I was afraid it would have to be done something like that.  Thanks, I'm gonna try it out.

Comment: @user2287873 Such is life, eh? :-)

Comment: oo it works perfectly, thx!  Now to count it out and figure out what data is in which location... I just hope that the rest of the patents follow the same spacing ==

Comment: Hmm actually an addendum, so you may notice that under the Correspondents field, the number of lines is variable, which makes the location of the data variable.  As it is, the query is returning each line in a separate node.  Is there a way to return it all in one node?              edit - well actually they are all p1 elements themselves damn

Comment: Maybe use regex to detect if an entry is a reel/frame entry and then count up from there.... maybe?

Comment: Perhaps, but you typically don't want to use regex for DOM parsing.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be using regex for parsing.  I'd be reading the result of each p1 result and seeing if it fits the form of a reel/frame entry.  Then knowing that the current p1 result is a reel/frame, i can know that in, say, 6 more results, I'm at an Assignee.

Comment: That sounded confusing.  What I mean is I'd still be using DOM, and just checking each $node->nodeValue to see if it passes the regex for being a reel/frame.

Comment: Yeah, sounds reasonable. Good luck.

Comment: Turned out to be a bit more involved than that but for the test cases it works :D.  Now to try it on the other million + patents.... hahaha

Comment: Just be sure to throttle your queries so you don't blow up that government website, haha.

Comment: Any suggestion for how much delay to put in?  I'd rather not blow them up haha.